# using bitmap with custom spinner

Tags: java, android, performance, bitmap, spinner

I used [this](http://abhiandroid.com/ui/custom-spinner-examples.html#comment-451) tutorial to make a custom spinner but now I'm  having a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 95976012 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 31MB until OOM`error. I am aware that I should use bitmaps I just don't know how to include the `bitmapFactory` in my `CustomAdapter`. I have already compressed my images to sizes less than 16kb and put them in the mipmap folder because they are icons. I have also already tried

```
    <application
            android:largeHeap="true"
</application>
```

Here's my code :

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.kathure.flags;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.R.attr.id;
import static android.graphics.BitmapFactory.*;
import static java.security.AccessController.getContext;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    String[] countryNames= {
            "Kenya" , "Malawi", "Nigeria", "Rwanda", "Tanzania", "Uganda"
    };


    int [] flags = {
            R.mipmap.kenyamin,R.mipmap.malawimin, R.mipmap.nigeriamin, R.mipmap.rwandamin, R.mipmap.tanzaniamin, R.mipmap.ugandamin
    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        //Getting the instance of Spinner and applying OnItemSelectedListener on it
        Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.simpleSpinner);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),flags,countryNames);
        spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), countryNames[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
package com.kathure.flags;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by kathure on 28/09/16.
 */

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    int flags[];
    String[] countryNames;
    LayoutInflater inflter;

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int[] flags, String[] countryNames) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.flags = flags;
        this.countryNames = countryNames;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return flags.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_items, null);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        icon.setImageResource(flags[i]);
        names.setText(countryNames[i]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you put the code?

Comment: Most likely your problem is elsewhere.  OOM means your application is out of memory.  If you have other places wasting memory, then you'll run OOM on whatever your next big allocation is.  Don't assume an OOM means that that object is actually the problem.